# Passing data from json object listview to new activity

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I'm new to android programming, but trying to learn some new stuff whenever I can, I have read lots of stuff on the website about my question, but it seems a bit confusing for me at the moment. What I wanted to know is how do I send the data from my listview which I populate from an external API and send it on item click to another activity, and on the new activity how do I retrieve it and for example set it on some edittext... I've done some examples without JSON data, and its fairly easy, but for some reason, i find it hard with JSON data. would appreciate any help

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String 
url="https://prokampo.000webhostapp.com/teste.php";

private ProgressDialog dialog;
private List<Item> array = new ArrayList<Item>();
private ListView listView;
private Adapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    adapter = new Adapter(this, array);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.show();
    sendRequest();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DadosLista.class);

            i.putExtra("data", adapter.toString());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}




//Creat volley request obj
private void sendRequest(){
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        hideDialog();
        //parsing json
        for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
            try{
                JSONObject obj=response.getJSONObject(i);
                Item item=new Item();
                item.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                item.setImage(obj.getString("image"));
                item.setRate(obj.getString("rating"));
                item.setYear(obj.getString("releaseYear"));

                //genre is json array
                 /*   JSONArray genreArray=obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                    ArrayList<String> genre=new ArrayList<String>();
                    for(int j=0;j<genreArray.length();j++){
                        genre.add((String) genreArray.get(j));
                    }
                    item.setGenre(genre);
*/
                //add to array
                array.add(item);
            }catch(JSONException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
});
    AppController.getmInstance().addToRequesQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

Comment: just in case some one needs for future reference, using cancit answer, on new activity you can get your data simply by 

        Item item = (Item) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data");

        txtTitle=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title2);
        txtTitle.setText(String.valueOf(item.getTitle()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement Serializable in your item class

```
public class Item implements Serializable{  
 ...
}
```

Then update your onItemClickListener

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DadosLista.class);
            i.putExtra("data", array.get(position));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Retrieve data in your DadosLista class's onCreate

```
Item item = (Item) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data");
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, should i use the adapter or the array? 
on my second activity i should have something like 

Item item = (Item) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data");

        txtTitle=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv_title2);
        txtTitle=item.getTitle().toString()
    
and now i can use this to get all the info from item of each position i click on the listview?

also when implementing serializable, do i need to add some extra steps inside my item class or just implement ?thank you

Comment: @lusitanos13 yes it should be array, i edited my answer. You don't have to add anything else to your Item class. It would work like you explained.

Comment: wow, its actually simple, thank you so much, got it working now need to figure out how to send my image through and send values that are not on my list, thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a singleton model in which you store the data. This way you can easily use the same data between activities.

If you implement it like this, you can then pass the position of which the user has clicked in the list to the next activity. In the next activity just get the item from the list at the given position.

Like this:

```
public class Model {
private static Model model;
private ArrayList<Item> items;

private Model() {
    items = new ArrayList();
}

public static Model getInstance() {
    if(model == null) model = new Model();
    return model;
}


public ArrayList<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(ArrayList<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
}
```

Then just keep a reference in each activity by doing this in the

```
onCreate() {
    model = Model.getInstance();
}
```